# Is there a standard for categorizing typefaces?

Tags: fonts, typography, terminology

So I was reading two documents on typography and each classifies font types in completely different categories.

- One document says we have : serif, sans serif, text, script, display and dingbats.
- The other document says we have : roman, egyptian, sans serif, script and miscellaneous (to attract attention).

I went over different websites and each seems to "make up" their own categories (like slab serif).

So is there a standard way of categorizing fonts or is every one free to invent his/her own categories?

Comment: Somewhat related (answers more than question): http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7722/how-to-identify-fantasy-fonts?rq=1

Comment: @e100 Yes, the answers complement what have been said below. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typefaces are a fairly rich area of creative evolution so there are a lot of different facets to them that can be described in a lot of ways.

The categories you give overlap each other, even within the same document.  For example, a display typeface can also be serif or sans-serif.  So they aren't all divided up into mutually exclusive categories; a typeface can belong to multiple categories based on its features.

Roughly put

- Serif/sans-serif refer to the presence or absense of serifs.
- Script typefaces are based on calligraphy (but usually not including blackletter, which is in a specific category of its own).
- Display/book refers to whether the typeface is intended for large short words like posters and logos, or lengthy body text such as in a book.  Not every typeface is one or the other, though.
- Roman is often used to describe traditional/transitional serif typefaces that *aren't* italics.
- Egyptian has been used in a couple of different ways; sometimes to describe a "slab serif" and at other times it's even been used to describe sans-serif.

There are also lots of other terms such as

- Grotesque, grotesk and gothic have been used as alternative terms for sans-serif.
- [Blackletter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackletter) is a specific type of hand-lettering very popular before the printing press.  Sometimes also called *gothic script* (not to be confused with either *gothic* or *script*).
- Italics are slanted forms of typefaces with some changes made to look more like hand-lettered text (that is a pretty basic, and inelegant, description).

and many more.

I'd probably generally group fonts into serif, sans-serif, script, and other (and possibly blackletter).  Other may include [stuff like this](http://www.fontspace.com/preview/charmap/9e6668ee5fe537b7b9a1bfff1c2370d5.png).

Comment: Okay! So what I must understand is that there is no consensus among type designers about what are primary, secondary,... font categories. That this is a field in constant evolution and one shouldn't cry for a typography crime when s/he sees a serif font categorized as display. This is a great answer... but I'll wait and see what others say. Thanks!

Comment: There will be a lot of consensus, but there will also be grey areas, that's all.  For instance, everyone will agree that there are serifs and sans-serifs, and among serifs there are traditional, transitional and modern, and among sans-serifs there are geometric, varying degrees of humanist, and more.  But different people will use different terms and categorisations for things that lie outside or between accepted categories.

Comment: @nt.bas it also helps to understand that few of the categories listed are mutually exclusive. For instance, a typeface can be categorized as both a serif and display.

Comment: @DA01 I don't follow. You said `mutually exclusive` but you say `can be...` which is inclusive for an example supposed to illustrate exclusivity. Are serif and display exclusive?

Comment: "Mutually exclusive" is when it is either one thing, or the other thing, but can never be both at once - there is no overlap.  As I said in my answer, categories "serif" and "display" are **not** mutually exclusive.  It's possible for a typeface to be both.  This is also the case with a number of the other categories mentioned.

Comment: Now i understand.The problem was in @DA01 comment, after mentioning mutually exclusive fonts, a reader would expect an illustration of mutually exclusive fonts because the next sentence started with "For instance...". Thanks

Comment: @nt.bas  It says *few* are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 5):

When it gets down to the really useful classifications, no there isn't consensus. The agreed upon categories are very broad and even there consensus is tentative.

Broadly accepted categories include:

- Garalde
- Venetian
- Transitional
- Scotch Roman
- Slab or Egyptian
- Modern
- Clarendon
- Grotesque
- Humanist
- Script
- Blackletter
- Fraktur
- Inscriptional

There are countless variations within the realm of type used for display.

If you're really interested in this topic, checkout **[Robert Bringhurst's Elements of Typographic Style](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/088179211X)**. He has an interesting historical model that makes good sense.

Comment: Thanks. I actually ordered the book right before posting the question. Expecting it this Friday!!! I have read a lot of good things about this book, hope it is really worth the money.

Comment: It's one of the greatest books available on the subject. Well worth the price. I'm also a big fan of Tschichold's The Form of the Book -- a collection of essays that deal largely with classical typography.

Comment: I got the book and it is a great one! Thanks a lot for recommending this book! +1 for that - at least until i get 15 rep!